# why visual studio 2015 enterprise load test runs only 100 users?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have following setting for my Step load test

Initial user = 100
Max User = 1000
Step duration = 600 seconds
Step user count = 100
Ramp time = 0

When I run load test, I only see test being run for 100 users.

My web test is just a login page to the website so I do not have any dynamic parametetrs.

Z

Comment: This may be not an technical issue, should be moved to another domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the question are:

- Initial user = 100
- Max User = 1000
- Step duration = 600 seconds
- Step user count = 100
- Ramp time = 0
- Test duration - unspecified but needed to fully explain what has happened

Your test starts running with 100 users. After 600 seconds it will add 100 users. After another 600 seconds it will add 100 more users. Thus just after 20 minutes of test execution there will be 300 users.

If the test duration is over 10 minutes then there should be more than 100 users.

Another possibility is that the run settings has `User test iterations == true` and the `Test iterations` stops the test before the 10 minutes has expired.

Comment: Make sense, I mistakenly thought step duration is total duration. My total duration is configured as 10 min so after that my tests were stopping and never going to 1000